# Prove that $C = \{(x_1,x_2,0)\in R^3 | x_1^2+x_2^2 \leq 1\}$ is closed, dim(C)=2 and find ri(C)

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> > Let $C = \{(x_1,x_2,0)\in R^3 | x_1^2+x_2^2 \leq 1\}$. Show that:
> >
> > (1) C is closed $\qquad\qquad$ (2) dim(C)=2 $\qquad\qquad$(3) int(C) = $\varnothing$
> >
> > (3) $ri(C) = \{(x_1,x_2,0)|x_1^2+x_2^2<1\}$

I have no idea on proceed on proof. Can anyone give me some hints?
Many thanks

Comment: @GAVD you mean *disk*, 'cuz *circle* is only the border

Answer (score 0):

(1) Show that its complement is opened in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

(2) What definition do you want to use? Approach may vary depending on answer. Still, note that dimension does not depend on embedding.

(3) Show that any open ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that contains a point of $C$ also contains points not in $C$.

(4) Consider the projection on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which simply forgets the last coordinate.

Comment: How to show a set is open. ri is interior

Comment: You want to show the interior is empty AND that it is equal to your last line?

Comment: In R^3, open sets can be taken as open balls B_r(p). They consist of all the points whose distance to p is less than r.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisGagnon: ri stands for relative interior. It is the interior relative to the affine hull of the set.